# How can I post changes to a list of players to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to post data to database but my viewmodel is empty when posting it to the controller, i tried different approaches, but everytime my viewmodel is null.

These are my classes :

```
 public class Player
 {      
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string PreName{ get; set; }
 }

public class Activitity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string WhichActivity { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Aanwezigheid
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ReasonEnum Reason{ get; set; }

    public int PlayerId{ get; set; }
    public Player Player{ get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players{ get; set; }

    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

My View Model :

```
public class PresenceVM
{
    public int PlayerId{ get; set; }

    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string PreName { get; set; }

    public ReasonEnum Reason { get; set; }
}
```

My HTTPGET for a list of players and I want to put the absence reason with the player in the database.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Presence(int id)
{
    var sp = _context.Players.ToList();

    foreach(Players s in sp)
    {
        var van = new PresenceVM
        {
            PlayerId = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name,
            PreName = s.PreName,
            ActivityId = id
        };

        list.Add(van);
    }

    return View(list);
}
```

My HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Presence(List<PresenceVM> list)
{
    var sp = _context.Players.ToList();
    var list = new List<Presence>();

    foreach (Players s in sp)
    {
        var van = new Aanwezigheid
        {
            PlayerId = s.Id,
            ActivityId = vm.ActivityId,
            Reason = vm.Reason
        };

        list.Add(van);
        _context.Presence.Add(van);
        //_context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Presence");
}
```

The problem is that my PresenceVm (viewmodel) does not get any data in true my controller. I don't understand why? Is it because of a list? With one item it's easy to post it to database. Maybe multiple items?

Edit 1:

The viewmodel for the Get & Post

```
@model IEnumerable<....ViewModels.PresenceVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Presence";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PreName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Reason")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PreName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Reason, "Present", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<form action="/Presences/Presence" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possibly the view has `@model IEnumerable<PresenceVM>` but the helpers inside it doesn't have naming indexes to be bound properly (please show view code to make sure).

Comment: the model that is passed into the view : @model IEnumerable<....ViewModels.PresenceVM>

Comment: I guess that in your view, you are using `@foreach`. Try with `@for` instead

Comment: Well, as expected, you're using `@foreach (var x in Model)` inside the view. Try using `@for (var i = 1; i < Model.Count; i++)` and put index for every model properties (e.g. `model[i].PlayerId`) instead.

Comment: You need a form in your POST view. How can you post smth to the server without a form?

Comment: In your GET, `foreach(Players in sp)` does this ***actually compile***?

Comment: It compiles , i also eddited the mistake..

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply copy/paste your code? What is `s` here `PlayerId = s.Id` in your `foreach(Players p in sp)`?

Comment: i changed it to a the language English so you would understand, normally it is in Dutch!

Comment: Oh okay then, thanks for your effort! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the form scope in wrong place (only include submit button). The correct way should include all properties you want to submit with indexes (since you're using `IEnumerable<PresenceVM>`, like this example:

```
<form action="/Presences/Presence" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PreName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Reason")
            </th>
        </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item[i].Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item[i].PreName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => item[i].Reason, "Present", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>

    <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that if you want to allow user input, you need to change all `DisplayFor` into `EditorFor`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Presence method is returning an object that does not exist (list).
It must return the view model if you want to use it in the post method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Presence(int id)
{
  List<PresenceVM> model = context.Players.Select(u => new PresenceVM
                           {
                             PlayerId = s.Id,
                             Name = s.Name,
                             PreName = s.PreName,
                             ActivityId = id
                           }).ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This, you do not really know. Maybe `list` is some static list from somewhere (although your code seems cleaner).

Comment: Can you explain yourself, please? Because it is not clear what you are saying

Comment: You said `list` is *"an object that does not exist"*. You do not have the full code of the controller, so you can not know if it exists or not

Comment: Ah ok. You have a point. I was just commenting from what I have saw in general code.

Comment: Unrelated: is there any reason why you create a `new List<PresenceVM>()` when you override `model` at the next line?

Comment: No. My mistake. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't use the `Form` [tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.100).aspx)

**VIEW**

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(("Presence"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    //divs

    <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

And it's better to pass a `Model` than a list of `Model`

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public IList<PresenceVM> MyList {get;set;}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Presence(MyViewModel xxx)
{
    //whatever
}
```